# Automate exporting images from Dynamic image file

Tags: javascript, json, photoshop, photoshop-script, after-effects

I am going to create a postal card (i don't know which one is better photoshop, After effects or ...). i want it to be dynamic. I mean using some config file(text or json or ...) next to it, provide the value of the dynamic layers and properties. then apply the config file to the postal card file from outside of the application, using a script. is it possible?

**1- which one is better photoshop, After effects or illustrator or ...?**

2- how should be the main script that applies the configuration file to the postal card file? javascript? C#? or sth else?

thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

1. I would use InDesign: itcan be scripted and has useful custom "templates" through Master Pages. It is also the Adobe product best suited for creating pdf files which is ideal for print. Photoshop is more for image manipulation, Illustrator is for vectors (often logos), and After Effects is for intense movie editing (special effects) -- so that won't help you very much.
2. Create your main script in javascript (because it is cross platform and well-known which means more people to answer your questions). Using javascript also helps to deal with transferring your data. You can use JSON to inject your data into the InDesign file.

This is possible, it just requires attention to detail. 
Good luck!